I used git bisect, found the commit with the bug, then reset. How do I find that commit again?
A few days ago, I used git bisect to find a commit that introduced a bug. I took note of it in a scratch file and ran git reset.
My computer restarted and I lost that note. Is there a way (using git commands) to get the commit from that note, or will I have to run git bisect again to find it?
I've been reading the git bisect help page, but I don't see any way to do this.

It’s probably one of the commits displayed by git reflog, if you remember enough to identify it from there.
